# How to create Service Account that has read-only Azure DevOps Git Credentials?

Tags: git, azure-devops, service-accounts

We are using Azure DevOps Git and we want to create a non-user Service Account (a bot) that can read from a git repository.

How do we actually achieve this in the system?  It is not obvious how to do this for a non-user service account bot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure DevOps services, the Service Account is automatically created for you when you create an organization in Azure DevOps Services. It is used when clients communicate with the hosted service and can be viewed through the web portal administration page.

If you are using Azure DevOps server, please refer to the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/account-requirements?view=azure-devops-2020

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies?view=azure-devops

Comment: I don't want to use Azure DevOps services though.  I want to create service account credentials for my own systems

Comment: You are thinking of a service account on the server side, but the question is about authorizing an automated client to access a git repo hosted in Azure DevOps.